# Concrete maths: converting a recurrence to a sum relation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

In the book concrete maths (2nd ed, page 27). The author explains of a way to solve recurrence in the following manner

---

Consider a general recurrence of form 
$a_n T_n = b_n T_{n-1} + c_n$

Multiply $s_n$ to both sides

$s_n a_n T_n =s_n  b_n T_{n-1} + s_n c_n$

such that $s_{n-1} a_{n-1} = s_n b_n$     -- eq(1)

substituting values

$s_n a_n T_n =s_{n-1}  a_{n-1} T_{n-1} + s_n c_n$

Let $s_n a_n T_n = F_n$

$F_n = F_{n-1}  + s_n c_n$

Hence  $$F_n = s_0 a_0 T_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k c_k$$

To choose $s_n$, consider equation 1
$$s_{n-1} a_{n-1} = s_{n} b_n$$
$$s_n = \frac{s_{n-1} a_{n-1}}{ b_n}$$

Expanding $s_{n-1}$

$$s_n = \frac{a_{n-1} a_{n-2} a_{n-3} ..... a_{1}}{b_n b_{n-1} b_{n-2} ... b_{2}}$$

---

Now this is the part that gets confusing, shouldn't there be a $s_1$ in conjugation with $a_1$. 
For example, consider $n=3$
$$s_3  = \frac{s_2 a_2}{b_3}$$
$$s_3 = \frac{\frac{s_1 a_1}{b_2} a_2}{b_3}$$
$$s_3 = \frac{s_1 a_1 a_2}{b_2 b_3}$$

---

Image of relevant  text in the book

[image: Text in the book that I am unable to understand]

Comment: Answered by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4214422/701444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised why it is so. Its my bad, the book did say that $s_1$ gets cancelled out so it can be anything except 0 and I missed it. But if anyone has the same question as me, here you go

Consider the equation
$$F_n = s_0 a_0 T_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k c_k$$
Since $s_{n-1}a_{n-1} = s_n b_n$, therefore
$$F_n = s_1 b_1 T_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k c_k$$ -- eq 1

Now lets look at the equation
$$s_n a_n T_n = F_n$$ -- eq 2

Combining the two equations we get
$$ T_n = \frac{s_1 b_1 T_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k c_k}{s_n a_n}$$
And it is here, where $s_1$ gets cancelled out

NOTE: $s_1$ has to be non zero

---

Here is the part that I initially missed
[image: The part that I initally missed]

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how $s_1$ disappeared from Equation (2.11). When you get from $s_n=s_{n-1}\frac{a_{n-1}}{b_n}$ to (2.11), there are no $T$ involved, it's pretty straightforward, and there is an $s_1$ missing. But if you're happy, I'll move on.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes, true , it doesnt explain that and it still bugs me, but I couldn't find or reason any other possible explanation. If there does exist another, I am more than happy to accept it.
<br>
Another thing that bugs me about this explanation is that for $k > 2$ in the expression $ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k c_k}{s_n a_n}$ . $s_1$ can not be cancelled out.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier oh no wait. I am an idiot. To solve the latter, even in that case $s_2$ can be expanded to get $\frac{s_1 a_1}{b_2}$ , which will then get canelled out .

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right. Sometimes in equations like this the first term $s_1$ disappears simply because it is equal to $1$, but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: thank you, but I just realised why it is the case
The answer was given in the book in fine text. $s_1$ gets canceled during $T_n = F_n / (s_n a_n)$. So $s_1$ can be any value except 1

Comment: @MeherwanGill Not sure I understand your comment, but if $s_1$ is not equal to $1$ and if the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are non-zero real or complex numbers, then Equation (2.11) from the book can't possibly hold.

Comment: I apolgize, my comment was a bit vauge. Look at the answer I posted , and see if it helps answer your concern